# please help me to solve this code

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I want to remove the following notice and warning from my code:

```
Warning: Missing argument 3 for User::readAll(), 
   called in /home/dz/rental/master/user/index.php on line 59 
   and defined in /home/dz/rental/objects/user.php on line 123 
Notice: Undefined variable: records_per_page 
   in /home/dz/rental/objects/user.php on line 124
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
class User{ 
    // koneksi database dan nama table
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "users";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $nama;
    public $email;
    public $username;
    public $password;

    // constructor
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function check_login(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " where (username=? or email=?) and password=?";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->username);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->email);                  
        $stmt->bindParam(3, md5($this->password));                      
        $stmt->execute();    
        $num = $stmt->rowCount();                 
        if($num==1){
            $user_data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);              
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user_data['nama'];
            return true;            
        }else{
            return false;        
        }        
    }

    public function get_session(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
            return $_SESSION['login'];  
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get_loggedinUser(){
        return $_SESSION['user'];
    }

    // Logout 
    public function user_logout(){
        $_SESSION['login'] = false;
        session_destroy();
    }
    // Sampai sini aja

    // simpan user
    public function create(){
        if($this->isUsernameAvailable($this->username, $this->email)==true){
            $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . " SET nama = ?, email = ?, username = ?, password = ?";

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

            $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->nama);
            $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->email);
            $stmt->bindParam(3, $this->username);
            $stmt->bindParam(4, md5($this->password));
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }           
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function isUsernameAvailable($uname, $email){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " where username=? or email=?";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $uname);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $email);                
        $stmt->execute();    
        $num = $stmt->rowCount();         
        if($num==0){
            return true;            
        }else{
            return false;        
        }
    }

    // ubah password
    public function ubahPassword(){
        $query = "UPDATE " . $this->table_name . " SET password = ? where id=?";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(1, md5($this->password));         
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    // hapus data user
    public function delete(){
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?";   
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);  
        if($result = $stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    function getBynama($nama){   
        $nama = "%$nama%";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " Where nama like ?";    
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $nama);  
        $stmt->execute();    
        return $stmt;
    }   

    public function readAll($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page){     
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " ORDER BY nama ASC LIMIT {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";  
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();    
        return $stmt;
    }

    // digunakan untuk paging
    public function countAll(){  
        $query = "SELECT id FROM " . $this->table_name . "";     
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();    
        $num = $stmt->rowCount();    
        return $num;
    }      

    public function readOne(){   
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " where id=? LIMIT 0,1";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);         
        $stmt->execute();    
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $this->nama = $row['nama'];
        $this->email = $row['email'];
        $this->password = $row['password'];
        $this->username = $row['username'];                     
    }    
}
?>
```

And this is the other

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Rental | Data user</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="/css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <?php
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/database.php';

    // instansiasi object database
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    // halaman yg diberikan melalui GET, halaman default adalah satu
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    // set jumlah data per halaman
    $records_per_page = 5;

    // query LIMIT clause
    $from_record_num = ($records_per_page * $page) - $records_per_page;

    // include file database dan object
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/objects/user.php';
    $user = new User($db);

    // query user
    if(isset($_GET['nama'])){
        $nama = $_GET['nama'];
        $stmt = $user->getBynama($nama);     
    }else{
        $stmt = $user->readAll($from_record_num, $records_per_page);
    }   
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();
    ?>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better usere display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">RENTAL.com</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Dzikri Syarif H <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/index.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#master"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-tags"></i> Data Master <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="master" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/master/mobil/index.php"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Data Mobil</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/master/pelanggan/index.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Data Pelanggan</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/master/produsen/index.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Data produsen</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#transaksi"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-credit-card"></i> Data Transaksi <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="transaksi" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Penyewaan</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Pengembalian</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#laporan"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-line-chart"></i> Laporan <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        <ul id="laporan" class="collapse">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car"></i> Data User</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> Penyewaan</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/master/user/index.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Users</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Data User <small>Data Master User </small>
                        </h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/master/user/index.php"><i class="fa fa-car"></i>Menu Utama</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>Master</li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Data User</a></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <a href="tambah.php" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Tambah</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
                                        <form action="index.php" method="GET">
                                           <div class="form-group input-group">
                                              <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="nama" class="form-control" placeholder="Cari Berdasarkan Nama User..." value="<? if(isset($nama)){ echo $nama;} ?>" />
                                                              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Cari" />
                                              </span>
                                           </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                <?php               
                // tampilkan data user jika ada
                if($num>0){ ?>          
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>No.</th>
                                            <th>Full Name</th>
                                            <th>User Name</th>
                                            <th>Password</th>
                                            <th>Is Active</th>
                                            <th>Aksi</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){   
                                        extract($row); 
                                    ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?= $id ?>
```

Comment: Where is the code itself?

Comment: i have edit my question, and i need your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have defined `User::readAll()` with three arguments in PHP code as:

```
/* Note that you have defined 3 arguments
   - $page
   - $from_record_num
   - $records_per_page
*/

public function readAll($page, $from_record_num, $records_per_page){     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " ORDER BY nama ASC LIMIT {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";  
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();    
    return $stmt;
}
```

But you are calling it in HTML part with three arguments as:

```
if(isset($_GET['nama'])){
    $nama = $_GET['nama'];
    $stmt = $user->getBynama($nama);     
}else{

    /* ------ Here you are calling it with two arguments ------- */

    $stmt = $user->readAll($from_record_num, $records_per_page);
}
```

The third argument is missing in your call in HTML code.

**Update:** You are missing `$page` argument in your call in HTML code, and in fact in definition, you never use it! So better to remove it to solve you problem.

Change your definition in PHP code as this:

```
/* Now you have only 2 arguments that matches your call.
   - $from_record_num
   - $records_per_page
*/
public function readAll($from_record_num, $records_per_page){     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " ORDER BY nama ASC LIMIT {$from_record_num}, {$records_per_page}";  
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();    
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: so, what should i do

Comment: do you think I should add one more argument?

Comment: @DzikriSyarifHidayatullah see the updated answer

Comment: oke brother, thankyou very much for help me

Comment: @DzikriSyarifHidayatullah If your problem is solved, I think you should accept my answer by clicking the tick mark at the left of the my answer, or else this will be floating as unanswered question

Comment: thx for helping him. I will follow thru with points !